# Twitter oauth with volley

Tags: java, android, rest, oauth, postman

I want to create an app that can post tweets to my twitter account.
I'm very new to coding and android so I'm struggling a lot here.
I can get a successful response using postman so i know my twitter API keys and secrets etc are correct.
But my question is. How do I take that postman request and turn it into something android can send.
Here's my first attempt.
I guess I'm not passing the tokens correctly?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView post_reponse_text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button post_request_button=findViewById(R.id.test);
        post_reponse_text=findViewById(R.id.get_response_data);

        post_request_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postRequest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void postRequest(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        String url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                post_reponse_text.setText("Post Data : " +response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                post_reponse_text.setText("Post Data : Failed");

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap <String, String>();
                params.put("screen_name", "realnamehere");
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("API Key", "placerealtokenshere");
                params.put("API Secret", "placerealtokenshere");
                params.put("TWITTER_ACCES_TOKEN", "placerealtokenshere");
                params.put("TWITTER_ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET", "placerealtokenshere");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Below is the curl request as supplied by twitter. How so i code that up?

```
curl --request POST \

  --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello%20world' \

  --header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_API_KEY", oauth_nonce="OAUTH_NONCE", oauth_signature="OAUTH_SIGNATURE", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="OAUTH_TIMESTAMP", oauth_token="ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"' \
```